# What is correct in the following sentences?

Tags: prepositions

The system shows 79 pcs in stock from the previous version of the V95830 harness.

The system shows 79 pcs in stock of the previous version of the V95830 harness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The preposition *from* is generally used in regards to past tense, so the second sentence is more grammatically correct. It rearranges the sentence structure of "*The system shows 79 pcs of the previous version of the V95830 harness in stock*".